# Set dynamic selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to pass dynamic selector in jQuery, 
Consider following example here I have one variable **$page** and I want to pass that as a selector to add class.
$page contains page name such as Dashboard, Maps, Profile etc,
Following code shows that how manually I added the selector, again one thing is that I don't want to use if-else conditions. Is it possible with any way?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var page = <?php echo json_encode($page);?>;
    $("#Dashboard").addClass('active');        //HERE TO PASS DYNAMIC SELECTOR
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we consider this `<?= json_encode($page); ?>` returns 'Dashboard' or 'Maps' ... 
You can simply do it like this:

[**Live jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wv5f9p8g/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var page = "<?= json_encode($page); ?>";
    $("#"+page).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: This is not working because we have to add selectors in quotes and as per your answer selector will be $(#dashboard)

Comment: Okay got it ITS WORKED, my mistake I'm passing name with small letter 'dashboard' and it is actually 'Dashboard' its a typographical error thanks for help